# Precincts where Clinton (and Obama) got <3% of the vote in 2016 and 2012?

Tags: united-states, voting, democracy

I remember asking about precincts that were basically/almost 100% Democrat. Now, I want to ask about if there are (close to) 100% Republican precincts, which is the opposite question. I would guess that they exist in the Texas Panhandle. I also want to know how many there were in 2012 because I would like to see if there was an increase. I asked the opposite question in the past. Are there any other precincts with over 200 votes where Hillary Clinton and Barack Obama (in 2012) received less than three percent of the vote?

Note: I relaxed the criteria somewhat because 100% Republican precincts are a lot rarer and less populated on average than 100% Democratic precincts, and changed 250 to 200 because of the rural nature of most or all such precincts.

Comment: Are you asking which precincts *are Republican*  (i.e. all or nearly all registered voters are members of the Republican party, or all or nearly all votes cast were for Republican candidates), or which precincts *didn't vote for a Democratic candidate* (at all or barely)? They aren't necessarily the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I examined the [2016 results](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/LYWX3D). There 155,000 precincts with at least 200 votes.

---

Eighty-nine such precincts had <3% Democratic votes. The majority were in the Deep South.

```
 State | Precincts 
-------+-----------
 AL    |        39
 AZ    |         1
 GA    |         3
 ID    |         1
 KS    |         1
 KY    |         1
 LA    |        15
 MS    |        10
 MT    |         1
 NE    |         1
 NJ    |         2
 SC    |         3
 TX    |         2
 UT    |         5
 WY    |         4
```

The twenty least Democratic precincts were:

```
 State |       County        |       Precinct       | D  |  R  | Total 
-------+---------------------+----------------------+----+-----+-------
 AL    | Washington County   | COPELAND ASSEMBLY OF | 1% | 78% |   382
 MS    | Neshoba County      | Fusky                | 1% | 98% |   331
 AL    | Crenshaw County     | PATSBURG DEPOT BLDG_ | 1% | 73% |   216
 NJ    | Ocean County        | Lakewood District 36 | 1% | 93% |   292
 AL    | Choctaw County      | LUSK                 | 1% | 73% |   266
 MT    | Ravalli County      | PCT 14               | 1% | 90% |   237
 MS    | Greene County       | Piave                | 1% | 96% |   314
 WY    | Campbell County     | Wright Town Hall 14- | 1% | 97% |   350
 AL    | Choctaw County      | BARRYTOWN            | 1% | 72% |   280
 LA    | LaSalle Parish      | 09 01                | 1% | 98% |   276
 AL    | Fayette County      | LEE-OAKRIDGE VOTING  | 1% | 64% |   205
 MS    | Lamar County        | Baxterville          | 2% | 97% |   348
 SC    | Williamsburg County | PINEY FOREST         | 2% | 57% |   402
 AL    | Lamar County        | VAILS                | 2% | 60% |   341
 AL    | Winston County      | MORELAND FIRE DEPT   | 2% | 58% |   279
 WY    | Crook County        | Moorcroft Outside -  | 2% | 94% |   332
 LA    | Vernon Parish       | 06 04                | 2% | 96% |   276
 GA    | Appling County      | 3A                   | 2% | 96% |   217
 TX    | Panola County       | 3650020              | 2% | 95% |   215
 TX    | Carson County       | 650402               | 2% | 97% |   211
```

All precincts of that minimum size had at least 1 Democratic vote.

---

For comparison, 4802 precincts had <3% Republican votes.

Twenty-five had *exactly zero* Republican votes, including:

```
 State |        County        |       Precinct       |  D   | R  | Total 
-------+----------------------+----------------------+------+----+-------
 AL    | Mobile County        | THOMAS SULLIVAN COMM | 53%  | 0% |   532
 IL    | Cook County          | Ward 20 Precinct 12  | 99%  | 0% |   438
 IL    | Cook County          | Ward 24 Precinct 35  | 99%  | 0% |   438
 OH    | Cuyahoga County      | CLEVELAND-02-R       | 99%  | 0% |   425
 IL    | Cook County          | Ward 09 Precinct 05  | 99%  | 0% |   423
 PA    | Philadelphia County  | 2170                 | 100% | 0% |   406
 LA    | Pointe Coupee Parish | 00 13A               | 99%  | 0% |   392
 PA    | Philadelphia County  | 2830                 | 100% | 0% |   350
 PA    | Philadelphia County  | 5890                 | 99%  | 0% |   312
 AL    | Wilcox County        | PORTABLE BUILDING    | 52%  | 0% |   303
 LA    | St. James Parish     | 00 07                | 100% | 0% |   292
 PA    | Philadelphia County  | 1230                 | 97%  | 0% |   285
 MD    | Baltimore city       | School No. 35|pplace | 98%  | 0% |   283
 PA    | Philadelphia County  | 7090                 | 100% | 0% |   282
 PA    | Philadelphia County  | 6230                 | 99%  | 0% |   280
 PA    | Philadelphia County  | 3430                 | 99%  | 0% |   268
 NY    | Kings County         | 056/56               | 94%  | 0% |   254
 IN    | Lake County          | G4-13                | 99%  | 0% |   231
 AL    | Wilcox County        | LOWER PEACHTREE DIST | 54%  | 0% |   220
 AR    | Desha County         | MITCHELLVILLE        | 59%  | 0% |   219
```

(Interestingly, Louisiana has two of the 20 least Democratic precincts and two of the 20 least Republican precincts.)

It's unclear how you want to treat independents,who played an unusually large role in 2016. FYI, only two precincts with >=200 votes actually had only Democratic votes.

---

There is a well-known phenomenon that Democratic votes are significantly more clustered. This gives a slight "natural gerrymandering" advantage to Republicans.

Comment: It turns out that I was right about them being in the Texas panhandle

Comment: @NumberFile, the 20th least Democratic district was in the Texas panhandle, yes.